# Push Notification action button is not displayed for all notifications when there are multiple notification

Tags: android, push-notification

In my app, I have implemented notification with single action button. When there are more than 10 notifications, the action button is displayed only for first few(3-4) notifications but not for other notifications. When I dismiss upper notifications then only I can see action button by tapping on that notification. Is this the expected behaviour or do I need to change implementation?

Comment: have you found any solution?